# express - catch request failed error

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I am using the request module to send requests to a URL

```
var req = require('request');
```

when the response is received, I would like to write that file on the node server, so I am piping it to crateWriteStream

```
req.get(myUrl)
     .on('error', function(err) {
        console.log('there is an error');
     })
.pipe(fs.createWriteStream('userdir/abc.png'));
```

This works fine if there is no error returned by req.get. In case req.get, fails I would like to not write the file locally and instead do something else.

I introduced .on('error'..) for this but the on('error') code never gets executed and .pipe tries to write the file that does not exist.

How can catch an error returned by req.get() and only write when there is no error.

Comment: Seems like request doesn't implement the on('error') event as you would expect, see https://github.com/request/request/issues/1779

Answer (score 0):

I think you are using streams but normally you can use the callback to receive the all information and then check if there is any error.

Personally I would do something like:

```js
var req = require('request');

req.get(myUrl, function (error, response, body) {
  if (error || response.statusCode != 200) {
    console.log(error) // Do something with your error
  }

  // If no errors, this code will be executed
  // Write in file
  
})
```